# How to get the list of shared notebooks using the Android Evernote SDK?

Tags: android, evernote

We are developing android application in which we are using Evernote Android SDK. We want to list the share folder (shared notebooks) and want to upload on it. We are using the following methods:

```
mEvernoteSession.getClientFactory().createNoteStoreClient().listSharedNotebooks(sharedCallback)
```

Via this method we get the guid. But it returns the guid of the folder (notebook) of current Evernote account which is shared to other Evernote account. But we want the details of the folders which is shared to the current Evernote account from other account.

We have tried various Evernote Android SDK methods but we cannot able to find the correct way. So I kindly request you all to provide me a correct way to proceed and share ideas regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

The list of notebooks shared to the current user can be obtained by [NoteStore#listLinkedNotebooks](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_listLinkedNotebooks). Then, you can access the owner's [SharedNotebook](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Types.html#Struct_SharedNotebook) by calling [NoteStore#authenticateToSharedNotebook](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_authenticateToSharedNotebook) and see the contents in it after. If you need more explanation of how sharing works on Evernote, the documentation is [here](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/sharing.php).